# Which tar options do I need to install node from binary on linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, tar

### Background

I downloaded binary for linux 64-bit and I was following several tutorials, each with similar options:

```
tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf /path/to/node.tar.gz
```

I always get this error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I've googled and it seems I have manually specified gzip file format via one of these switches. File is actually `tar.xz`, not `tar.gz`. It was probably `tar.gz` in older versions.

I wonder what do all of these options mean and which one's I need?
Is there an auto-detect format option?

This is what running `info tar` said:

```
 -C, --directory DIR
       change to directory DIR

 --strip-components=NUMBER
       strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction

 -x, --extract, --get
       extract files from an archive

 -z, --gzip, --gunzip --ungzip

 -f, --file ARCHIVE
       use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```

### Questions

I don't understand options `-f`, `--strip-components`.

`-f` - What else can it be but a file? What is "device archive"?

`--strip-components` - What does `--strip-components 1` exactly do here?
I don't see any numbers in the file.
Please provide example of filename which would be affected by `--strip-components` and explain how.

And what's the idea with installing nodejs on linux?
Just unzip to `/usr/local` or what else needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

First, `tar` is "smart" enough to detect the compression method used in an archive so it isn't necessary to specify -z or -j.

> -f - What else can it be but a file? What is "device archive"?

A device archive could be a tape archive attached to your machine in /dev/your_tar

> --strip-components - What does --strip-components 1 exactly do

```
tar xfz /var/www/site/site.gz --strip-components=2
```

will create /var/site.

Comment: If files inside the archive have x number of names in it's file name e.g. /var/www/site/site.html, --strip-components=2 will strip the outputted file to /var/site.html

Comment: So did you mean it will create /var/site in your answer? Why /tmp/site?

Comment: Correct, that was my mistake. Fixed.